# What is causing XML error on browser refresh in child pages?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a serverless api app written in Angular5 on AWS. Everything is working as expected in it, except I just discovered something while testing it.

If I click on the menu items and sign up (an email is sent to the sign up user with a confirmation code), I can confirm and then log in. It is a popular course with three settings one can create: age, height, and income. Once a set is added to the database, the user can recall data he has already uploaded and compare it to other data in the database.

The comparison displays from a child page under the domain root (/compare). Let's say a user is on that page and she decides to refresh the browser. I have read questions on this forum about how to redirect from a child page upon browser refresh, so that may be a solution for something more elegant than what I'm getting.

Now on refresh I'm getting this in Firefox:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

Error: 

Access Denied

Request Id:
1C649DAB28218FAD

Host Id:
IaIZ7xZSkky9Fd1IwXIr8V5VCSQ/74VfTGZlh6RM91ycUASHVTY8r6J3TGS4ySn1EWOCedeS4/0=
```

and even more on Chrome:

```
try { Object.defineProperty(navigator, "globalPrivacyControl", { value: false, configurable: false, writable: false }); document.currentScript.parentElement.removeChild(document.currentScript); } catch(e) {};
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

Error

Access Denied

RequestId: 7B4D5C747CAE3944

HostId:
ounTFQE3P6CMVrfYkN9IdQq8/o85g/FsSPb9efmiTjhfOre7R7idWZz783kw6RaqYtC8z4yk9HU

(function () { if (typeof navigator.getUserMedia !== "undefined") navigator.getUserMedia = undefined; if (typeof window.MediaStreamTrack !== "undefined") window.MediaStreamTrack = undefined; if (typeof window.RTCPeerConnection !== "undefined") window.RTCPeerConnection = undefined; if (typeof window.RTCSessionDescription !== "undefined") window.RTCSessionDescription = undefined; // if (typeof navigator.mozGetUserMedia !== "undefined") navigator.mozGetUserMedia = undefined; if (typeof window.mozMediaStreamTrack !== "undefined") window.mozMediaStreamTrack = undefined; if (typeof window.mozRTCPeerConnection !== "undefined") window.mozRTCPeerConnection = undefined; if (typeof window.mozRTCSessionDescription !== "undefined") window.mozRTCSessionDescription = undefined; // if (typeof navigator.webkitGetUserMedia !== "undefined") navigator.webkitGetUserMedia = undefined; if (typeof window.webkitMediaStreamTrack !== "undefined") window.webkitMediaStreamTrack = undefined; if (typeof window.webkitRTCPeerConnection !== "undefined") window.webkitRTCPeerConnection = undefined; if (typeof window.webkitRTCSessionDescription !== "undefined") window.webkitRTCSessionDescription = undefined; })();
```

I have not the slightest idea what is going on there. Can someone please enlighten me?

Even in the less extensive Firefox return it seems pretty awkward giving the user all that error information, Request Id and Host Id.

Comment: Is Cloudflare used here?

Answer (score 0):

The navigator in your web application is not configured properly. It is being directed to a location that does not exist or is logically not correct.